# Listing all public image templates

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

How do you list all of public image templates like the list you would get by going to "Devices" -> "Manage" -> "Images" then selecting "Public Images"?

I can see that using "SoftLayer_Account", there are these operations I can do that are related:

```
getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups();
getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups();
getSharedBlockDeviceTemplateGroups();
```

And "SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group" offers

```
getPublicCustomerOwnedImages();
```

which the getPublicCustomerOwnedImages() gives the closest to what I want,
except that it seems to exclude those created by "SoftLayer Technologies, Inc.".

So which API will give me the whole list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to uset these method:

to get the public images:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getPublicImages

to get the private images:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getBlockDeviceTemplateGroups

Regards

Comment: Cool. I missed the getPublicImages().  I guess I was focusing on searching for "template".